# Why can't I get any miner to work on my PC?

Tags: cgminer, bfgminer, guiminer

I've tried BFGminer, CGminer, and GUIminer. I'm registered on Slush's Pool. I can't get BFGminer.exe to even open though and GUIminer refuses to connect to Slush's Pool even if I manually put in the new address. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help me? I'm super new to this if you can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mine Bitcoin on a desktop (or laptop) computer these days.  If you are trying to mine Bitcoin on Slush, you will need an ASIC.  You can potentially mine ZCash on Slush, *if* you have a high performance graphics card.  Slush does not support directly mining any other coins.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't mine BTC on your normal PC or laptop because now bitcoin blockchain dificulty lavel is too high . So you have to mine using cloud mining system and best performanable machine (E.G. Intel i9 board & processor, 8 GB  DDR 4 RAM, Coller master SMPS also with a 1000 watt power supply and Nvidia TitanXP - Pascal - 3840 Cuda Cores - 12GB GDDR5X ) .

That is a only one way to mine BTC now days .

Comment: Mining on any kind of CPU is pointless now, ASICs are the only way you'll see any returns. Additionally, the wast majority of cloud mining is a scam.